# How to get access token from one MVC5 application to another MVC5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am trying to get access token from one .net MVC application to another MVC application. My requirement is :
I have Two .net MVC projects "A" and "B" under the same solution, where authentication is done under the project "A". I want Project "B" to consume the authentication token from project "A".

Please suggest a suitable approach.

Comment: A bit more detail might help: what sort of access token do you use? how do you pass it along within one application? do you run full .net framework or .net core? do you run this on Windows IIS or Linux/Docker?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is called Single Sign On (SSO) where an user logged into one app can automatically log onto another. But your approach is not right. App 'B' should not get token from App 'A', rather go directly to 'Auth Server' and get a token from there. Since the user is already logged on, 'Auth Server' will not ask for credentials again and pass on the tokens (if user has permitted App 'B') directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can share authentication cookies between your apps. I implemented this solution in a portal that was split into multiple projects and subdomains.

**ASP.NET Core:**

[Share authentication cookies among ASP.NET apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

**ASP.NET 4.x:**

[Sharing Authorization Cookies](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SharingAuthorizationCookiesBetweenASPNET4xAndASPNETCore10.aspx)